# HTML code inside an angularjs expression

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to render html codes inside an angularjs expression? Something like this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        {{
            1+2 === 3 ? 
            '<span>Hello World!</span>' 
                : 
            "HI" 
        }}
    </body>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Care to provide a code? Documentation seems to not answer clearly and precisely my question

Comment: Great, two answers suggest to use a different solution, and one comment by dirkk says it is easy and gives us a hint. In the end nobody gives the answer, which is what people come here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's definitely a better solution to this using `ng-if`. Having these huge angular expressions with HTML inside defeats the purpose in my opinion. What I'd do is something like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <span ng-if="1 + 2 === 3">Hello World!</span>
    <p ng-if="1 + 2 !== 3">HI</p>
</body>
```

This a lot more readable to me.

Comment: Oh ok seems like I really need to use that method I was hoping I can use something similar to Django's conditional template tags

Comment: You could also use `ngBindHtml` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml , but this solution seems a lot nicer if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

**Expression** are used for something to be parsed but for your required condition you can simply use `ng-if` like:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <span ng-if="1+2 === 3">Hello World!</span> 
        <span ng-if="1+2 !== 3">HI</span>  
</body>
```

Comment: Oh ok seems like I really need to use that method I was hoping I can use something similar to Django's conditional template tags